# Pass an array of records to set a hasMany relationship without the records in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, has-many

I'm saving a new 'owner' record and have the following fields:

```
export default Model.extend({
    "owner": attr('string'),
    "cars": DS.hasMany('car',{async: true}),
});
```

In this example, I have a cars field. This would relate to the car model and show how many cars the owner has in his collection.  However, let us say no cars exist, or I want to add the owner record without adding cars he owns... I get this error:

```
"Assertion Failed: You must pass an array of records to set a hasMany relationship"
```

How would I got about saving this record, so I can add cars or possibly keep with no cars?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You can just leave the relation empty. Do you have the problem when you create your record or when you parse the server response?

Comment: I'm leaving it empty, when I go create a new record,  I get the Assertion Failed error above.

Comment: Thats [working](https://ember-twiddle.com/9118887230cbf9b244358dc32b1f54ca?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C). Try to provide a not working twiddle.

Comment: I see what was going on, I was passing cars = "" rather than just having it set to undefined/null.  Thank you for the responses.